# Comparing predictability of outcomes across leagues

Tags: hypothesis-testing, error, differences

From time to time I encounter newspaper articles with titles like “Unpredictable English Premier League Keeps Us Guessing”, which make claims about the difference in predictability of outcomes across leagues. My question is: how would one test such claims?

The method that I thought of (and later found at https://theconversation.com/just-how-unpredictable-is-the-premier-league-scientists-have-done-the-maths-59839) has one compute the average MSE between predictions (based on betting odds) and actual outcomes. But what test should be employed for comparing such averages?